# Run exe file alongside .NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an executable file which I would like to run alongside a .NET Core web application. It needs to start when the web application loads and will continuously run until the web application ends. I also need to be able to check if the executable file is still running through the UI, and have an option to start, stop or restart.

I have done a bit of googling already on this and all that keeps returning is examples where the exe file is expected to end at some point, not anything that continuously runs.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: i would start an `IHostedService` that monitors it. You can catch when a program exit using the Process API, then restart if detected. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Is there any chance you can trigger the execution with something like P/Invoke? Otherwise, I suggest you to run it as a service, and monitor with IProgress and cancellation token

Answer (score 0):

Andy's comment is correct. It's recommended to using [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

And you also can use signalr to record the status of your service. You can start, stop by using `StartAsync and StopAsync`. And it's impossible to restart. The background service was launched with asp.net core.

For more details, you can check the blog:

[Communicate the status of a background job with SignalR](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/)